# In javascript i want to preserve my angle addition after 360 degrees to 360 + and not again from 0 degrees

Tags: javascript, transition, angle, rotatetransform

While transform rotate in javascript whenever I add anything to 360 drgree, it again starts counting from 0 degree and my rotated div reverts backwards to 0 deg if I use transition. I want my rotation to continue in same direction. Please help

Comment: Can you post some code that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Angles are limited to 360 degrees. The browser automatically converts higher degrees modulo 360. Why do you think you need higher angles to be preserved as is? It doesn't affect the transformation.

Comment: @ControlAltDel... i tried it and its working... i will paste the code here... thanks a lot

Comment: @Barmar ... i needed rotation... i will paste the code here and post the working also... thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

[image]
i tried my issue separately... and it is working...

```
<style>
        .container-div {
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            border: 2px solid #000;
            position: relative;
        }
        .center-div {
            position: absolute;
            margin: auto;
            top:0;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
            border: 1px solid #f00;
            transform: rotate(0deg);
            transition: all 0.3s linear;
        }
        .rotate-click {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100px;
            height: 30px;
            line-height: 30px;
            background-color: #000;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>

<div class="container-div">
        <div class="center-div"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rotate-click">rotate</div>

    <script>
        let angle = 0;
        document.querySelector(".rotate-click").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
            angle += 45;
            document.querySelector(".center-div").style.transform = `rotate(${angle}deg)`;
            console.log(angle);
        });
    </script>
```

thanks to @ControlAltDel and @Barmar

Comment: You need to post the failing code in the question, and the answer should explain how you fixed it.

Comment: sure @Barmar... actually it is my company code so I cant make public... that is the reason i coded the idea separately  and displayed here the result... next time onwards i will keep this in mind and do the right thing... thanks

Comment: It doesn't have to be the real code with proprietary information, it can be a simpler [mre].